# Error when plotting graph in specific dates in R

Tags: r

Could you help me understand why I can't generate the graph for 02/07 and 03/07, however for 01/07, I can? I inserted the executable code below.

Note that my `dmda` is like 01/07, and the graph is generated. When I insert `dmda` as 02/07 or 03/07, it gives an error in the `mod` variable, but I don't understand why.

Thanks!

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- structure(
  list(date1 = c("2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28",
                 "2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28"),
       date2 = c("2021-04-02","2021-04-03","2021-04-08","2021-04-09","2021-04-10","2021-07-01","2021-07-02","2021-07-03"),
       Week= c("Friday","Saturday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Thursday","Friday","Monday"),
       DR01 = c(14,11,14,13,13,14,0,0), DR02= c(14,12,16,17,13,12,0,0),DR03= c(19,15,14,13,13,12,0,0),
       DR04 = c(15,14,13,13,16,12,13,0),DR05 = c(15,14,15,13,16,12,13,11),
       DR06 = c(21,14,13,13,15,16,13,11),DR07 = c(12,15,14,14,19,14,13,11)),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

dmda<-"2021-07-01"

datas<-df1 %>%
  filter(date2 == ymd(dmda)) %>%
  summarize(across(starts_with("DR"), sum)) %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_pattern = "DR(.+)", values_to = "val") %>%
  mutate(name = as.numeric(name))
colnames(datas)<-c("Days","Numbers")

dif <- as.Date(dmda) - as.Date(df1$date1[1]) + 1
datas <- datas[dif:max(datas$Days, na.rm = TRUE),]

plot(Numbers ~ Days, xlim=c(0,8), ylim=c(0,20), data = datas,xaxs='i')
mod <- nls(Numbers ~ b1*Days^2+b2,start = list(b1 = 0,b2 = 0), data = datas)
new.data <- data.frame(Days = with(datas, seq(min(Days),max(Days),len = 45)))
new.data <- rbind(0, new.data)
lines(new.data$Days, predict(mod, newdata=new.data))
points(0, coef(mod)[2], col="red", pch=19, cex=1.2, xpd=TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Except for the one you showed '2017-07-01', the others are filtering with just a single unique 'Numbers' value

Comment: i.e. suppose you change the value to a single one in the working date, it shows the same error i.e. `datas$Numbers <- 14;
> nls(Numbers ~ b1*Days^2+b2,start = list(b1 = 0,b2 = 0), data = datas)#
Error in nls(Numbers ~ b1 * Days^2 + b2, start = list(b1 = 0, b2 = 0),  : 
  singular gradient`

Comment: Thanks for reply! Is there any way to resolve this? Because I thought it was to generate the graph.

Comment: You are subsetting from `dif` to max of dates and there are duplicates elemetns in Numbers.  Sometimes, you get only a single value for "Number".  You may need to change the logic

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to face your problem. Let's do it a bit differently.
First, let's load the libraries we need and load your data.

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- structure(
  list(date1 = c("2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28",
                 "2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28"),
       date2 = c("2021-04-02","2021-04-03","2021-04-08","2021-04-09","2021-04-10","2021-07-01","2021-07-02","2021-07-03"),
       Week= c("Friday","Saturday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Thursday","Friday","Monday"),
       DR01 = c(14,11,14,13,13,14,0,0), DR02= c(14,12,16,17,13,12,0,0),DR03= c(19,15,14,13,13,12,0,0),
       DR04 = c(15,14,13,13,16,12,13,0),DR05 = c(15,14,15,13,16,12,13,11),
       DR06 = c(21,14,13,13,15,16,13,11),DR07 = c(12,15,14,14,19,14,13,11)),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Now we're going to mutate them, but a bit differently than you do.

```
fDays = function(data, date2){
  firstDay = interval(data$date1[1], date2) %>% as.duration() %/% ddays(1)
  data %>% pivot_longer(starts_with("DR"), values_to = "Numbers") %>% 
    mutate(Days = 1:nrow(.)) %>% 
    filter(Days>firstDay) %>% 
    select(Days, Numbers)
}

df2 = df1 %>% as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(
    date1 = date1 %>% ymd(),
    date2 = date2 %>% ymd()    
  ) %>% group_by(date2) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  group_modify(~fDays(.x$data[[1]], .y$date2)) %>% 
  nest()
```

This requires some comment. First, notice that I converting your variables `date1` and `date2` to a POSIXct type (`date1 = date1%>% ymd()`). Then I collapse the data with the `nest` function.
After this operation, we have something like this:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 2
# Groups:   date2 [8]
  date2      data            
  <date>     <list>          
1 2021-04-02 <tibble [1 x 9]>
2 2021-04-03 <tibble [1 x 9]>
3 2021-04-08 <tibble [1 x 9]>
4 2021-04-09 <tibble [1 x 9]>
5 2021-04-10 <tibble [1 x 9]>
6 2021-07-01 <tibble [1 x 9]>
7 2021-07-02 <tibble [1 x 9]>
8 2021-07-03 <tibble [1 x 9]>
```

Where the value of the variable `date` in the observation on "7/21/2021" looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 9
  date1      Week      DR01  DR02  DR03  DR04  DR05  DR06  DR07
  <date>     <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 2021-06-28 Thursday    14    12    12    12    12    16    14
```

Then we use the function `fDays`. However, here we need to consider the logic of the function for a longer time.
As I noticed in your program you counted `dif`. In my program it is `firstDay+1`. The problem is that for the value `date1="2021-06-28"` and for `date2="2021-04-02"` this value is `-86`. What should be done in this case, unfortunately, I do not know. I just assumed that for negative values, `fDays` will return all brew days with their numbers.
So in the end my `df2` tibble looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 2
# Groups:   date2 [8]
  date2      data            
  <date>     <list>          
1 2021-04-02 <tibble [7 x 2]>
2 2021-04-03 <tibble [7 x 2]>
3 2021-04-08 <tibble [7 x 2]>
4 2021-04-09 <tibble [7 x 2]>
5 2021-04-10 <tibble [7 x 2]>
6 2021-07-01 <tibble [4 x 2]>
7 2021-07-02 <tibble [3 x 2]>
8 2021-07-03 <tibble [2 x 2]>
```

Where the `date` for `"2021-04-02"` looks like

```
# A tibble: 7 x 2
   Days Numbers
  <int>   <dbl>
1     1      14
2     2      14
3     3      19
4     4      15
5     5      15
6     6      21
7     7      12
```

and for `"2021-07-03"` it looks like this

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
   Days Numbers
  <int>   <dbl>
1     5      13
2     6      13
3     7      13
```

Now all we have to do is create charts. But here we run into problems again. First, we need to ask if it makes sense to build an `nls` model for 2 or 3 observations? Second, can we draw the prediction line down to the 0 Days point? I assume you thought about the answers to these questions.
So it's time to prepare the plots.

```
fPlot = function(data, date2){
  p = data %>% ggplot(aes(Days, Numbers))+
    geom_point()+
    xlim(0, max(data$Days))+
    ggtitle(date2)
  tryCatch(
    {
      mod <- nls(Numbers ~ b1*Days^2+b2, data, list(b1=0,b2=0))
      df = tibble(
        Days = c(0,seq(min(data$Days), max(data$Days), length.out = 45)),
        Numbers = predict(mod, newdata=tibble(Days=Days))
      )
      p + geom_line(data=df)+
        geom_point(data=df[1,], size = 3, color = "red")
    }, error = function(msg){p}
  )
}

df2 %>% group_map(~fPlot(.x$data[[1]], .y$date2))
```

Note, however, that due to specific values or a small number of observations, the `nls` function may return errors. Therefore, it was called in `tryCatch`.
When an error occurs, the plot will only contain points. When all goes well, a prediction line will appear on the graph.
Here are a few selected plots
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]